# Java regex match with slash

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I want to match words "N/A" or "None".

So I used

```
public static final String NA = "/^(n\\/a|none)$/i";
```

It doesn't work in java. Can you help?

Comment: regex= (?i)n[/|\\\]a|none, string literal= (?i)n[/|\\\\\]a|none

Comment: Do you want to *find* these words, or do you want to test if the whole string is one of these words?

Answer (score 2):

Java does not use `/` as a regular expression literal. (No need to escape `/` itself). If you want to ignore case, you can use a modifier `(?i)` inside the regular expression:

```
String NA = "^(?i)(n/a|none)$";
```

Or, you can use [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) when you compile the pattern.

```
String NA = "^(n/a|none)$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(NA, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: @Feng, You're welcome. BTW, I forgot to mention that you don't need to escape `/`.

Answer (score 0):

To match "N/A" or "None" in Java use:

```
(?i)\b(?:n/a|none)\b
```

As escaped java String:

```
"(?i)\\b(?:n/a|none)\\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks for a forward or backward slash

The regular expression would be written as `(?i)n[/|\\]a|none`

To use this in a String you'll need to escape the backward slash:

```
String pattern = "(?i)n[/|\\\\]a|none";

String[] array = 
    {
        "N/a",
        "n\\a",
        "NonE",
        "na"
    };

for(String item : array)
{
    System.out.println("\"" + item + "\" = " + item.matches(pattern));
}
```

Console:

```
"N/a" = true
"n\a" = true
"NonE" = true
"na" = false
```